# Вывод присвоенного значения

Tags: cmd

Я хочу написать батник, в котором буду присваивать переменной r определенное значение с последующим выводом значения этой переменной в несколько текстовых файлов, созданных с помощью

```
for /I
```

Но у меня не получается вывести в .txt значение, определенное с помощью

```
set
```

Начал эксперименты непосредственно с самой командной строкой:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Последние 3 команды да, они выводят значение r, но эти значения окружены соответствующими символами, чего не нужно. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как делать правильно?

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался, оказывается, и в батнике, и в командной строке ВАЖНО!, чтобы между закрывающим процентом и >> был пробел. То есть, уже код

```
set /a r=5
echo %r% >>file.txt
```

из командной строки сделает свое дело.